# Python3 match, reverse match and dedupe

Tags: python, string-matching, python-dedupe

The intention of the code below is to process the two dictionaries and add matching `symbol` values from each dictionary to the `pairs` list if the value contains the item in `cur` but not if the value contains either item in the `curpair` list.

I'm successful with the value matching `cur` but I can't figure out how to do the reverse match against the items in `curpair`.  Also, a secondary issue is that it seems to create duplicates, likely because of the additional `for` loop to compare against the items in `curpair`.  Either way, I'm not sure if there's a way to dedupe in-line or if that needs to be another routine.

I'm sure there may be a way to do all of this, and simplify the code at the same time, with list comprehension, but maybe not.  My trying to understand list comprehension only results in reassuring me that my Python experience is far too brief to be able to make sense of that yet :)

Grateful for any insights.

```
cur='EUR'
curpair=['BUSD', 'USDT']

def get_pairs(tickers):
    pairs = []
    for entry in tickers:
        if cur in entry['symbol']:
            for cp in curpair:
                if cp not in entry['symbol']:
                    pairs.append(entry['symbol'])
    return pairs

# d1 and d2 @ https://pastebin.com/NfNAeqD4
spot_pairs_list = get_pairs(d1)
margin_pairs_list = get_pairs(d2)
print(f"from d1: {spot_pairs_list}")
print(f"from d2: {margin_pairs_list}")
```

Output:

```
from d1: ['BTCEUR', 'BTCEUR', 'ETHEUR', 'ETHEUR', 'BNBEUR', 'BNBEUR', 'XRPEUR', 'XRPEUR', 'EURBUSD', 'EURUSDT', 'SXPEUR', 'SXPEUR', 'LINKEUR', 'LINKEUR', 'DOTEUR', 'DOTEUR', 'LTCEUR', 'LTCEUR', 'ADAEUR', 'ADAEUR', 'BCHEUR', 'BCHEUR', 'YFIEUR', 'YFIEUR', 'XLMEUR', 'XLMEUR', 'GRTEUR', 'GRTEUR', 'EOSEUR', 'EOSEUR', 'DOGEEUR', 'DOGEEUR', 'EGLDEUR', 'EGLDEUR', 'AVAXEUR', 'AVAXEUR', 'UNIEUR', 'UNIEUR', 'CHZEUR', 'CHZEUR', 'ENJEUR', 'ENJEUR', 'MATICEUR', 'MATICEUR', 'LUNAEUR', 'LUNAEUR', 'THETAEUR', 'THETAEUR', 'BTTEUR', 'BTTEUR', 'HOTEUR', 'HOTEUR', 'WINEUR', 'WINEUR', 'VETEUR', 'VETEUR', 'WRXEUR', 'WRXEUR', 'TRXEUR', 'TRXEUR', 'SHIBEUR', 'SHIBEUR', 'ETCEUR', 'ETCEUR', 'SOLEUR', 'SOLEUR', 'ICPEUR', 'ICPEUR']
from d2: ['ADAEUR', 'ADAEUR', 'BCHEUR', 'BCHEUR', 'BNBEUR', 'BNBEUR', 'BTCEUR', 'BTCEUR', 'DOTEUR', 'DOTEUR', 'ETHEUR', 'ETHEUR', 'EURBUSD', 'EURUSDT', 'LINKEUR', 'LINKEUR', 'LTCEUR', 'LTCEUR', 'SXPEUR', 'SXPEUR', 'XLMEUR', 'XLMEUR', 'XRPEUR', 'XRPEUR', 'YFIEUR', 'YFIEUR']
```

Comment: Would you mind including an example of what the input looks like? That'd really help to understand what you're trying to do. Edit: Ok I found the link haha it's still better to include a sample input for future reference since the external source might become unavailable in the future.

Comment: No doubt it’s better in-line.  I wasn’t sure exactly how much output would be appropriate to get across the point of what I was trying to do, with proper examples of the input.  I decided to err on the side of caution and link it all.  I do appreciate your point though.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with double values can easily be solved by using `set` instead of `list`.

As for the other problem, this loop isn't doing the right thing:

```
for cp in curpair:
    if cp not in entry['symbol']:
        pairs.append(entry['symbol'])
```

This will append the symbol to the list if any of the elements in `curpair` is missing. For example, if the first `cp` is not in `symbol`, it's accepted even if the second element *is* in `symbol`. But it seems that you want to include only symbols that include *none* of the elements in `curpair`.

In other words, you only want to append if `cp in symbol` is `False` for all `cp`.

This, indeed, can easily be done with list comprehensions:

```py
def get_pairs(tickers):
    pairs = set() # set instead of list
    
    for entry in tickers:
        symbol = entry['symbol']
        if cur in symbol and not any([cp in symbol for cp in curpair]):
            pairs.add(symbol) # note it's 'add' for sets, not append
    
    return pairs
```

`[cp in symbol for cp in curpair]` is the same as this (deliberately verbose) loop:

```
cp_check = []

for cp in curpair:
    if cp in curpair:
        cp_check.append(True)
    else:
        cp_check.append(False)
```

So you will get a list of `True` and `False` values. `any()` returns `True`
if any of the list elements are `True`, i.e., it basically does the opposite
of what you want. Hence we need to reverse its truth value with `not`, which will give you `True` if all of the list elements are `False`, exactly what we need.

Comment: Grateful for the response.  Thanks for the detailed explanation on the logic behind this.  It makes perfect sense and it works perfectly now.